# Proof that $f(x)=4x^4-2x+1$ has no real roots.

Tags: calculus

My thought was to:
1) hypothesis there are 2 real roots for this equation,
2) apply Rolle's theorem and come to a reductio ad absurdum
and then if there aren't 2 real roots, it has to be 1. If there is 1 real root, this means that it has to have 3 non-real roots. But non real roots come in pairs, so either is 2 real- 2 non real, either 0 real- 4 non real. Therefore, it has no real roots.

In case my thought is correct, the problem is that $f'(x)=0 => x^3=1/8$ doesn't lead me in reductio ad absurdum, because it has 1 real and 2 non- real roots.
I'm stuck and I'm about to punch the desk. Please, release me from this martyrdom.

Comment: And why do you demand a *reductio ad absurdum*?

Comment: @Bernard, my bad actually. It was the only thing that came into my mind at first place and then I was desperately trying to solve it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- $f'(x)=2(8x^3-1)$,  so there's a single critical point: $\; x=\frac12$.
- $f''(x)=48x^2\ge 0$, so by the second derivative test, this critical point is a  *minimum*, and this minimum is an absolute minimum.
- $f(\frac12)=\frac14>0$.

Comment: Actually there is no need to compute the second derivative in this case (although it can't hurt): as function is continuous and diverges to $+\infty$ for $x$ going both to $\pm\infty$ there has to be at least one minimum. As there is only one critical point, it must be that one.

Comment: @b00nheT: That's right, but it more or less supposes some familiarity with the general look of quartic function curves. I preferred  some general conclusive evidence.

Comment: Of course @Bernard. It's just that sometimes I feel like the geometry of the curve gets completely neglected due to these automatic "sign of derivative" approaches :)

Comment: I share your point of view., and I must say I first thought exactly like you. Then I wondered at which level was supposed to be asked.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the derivative to find the minimum.

Comment: Oh thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compute $$f(1/2)=4(1/2)^4-2(1/2)+1=\frac{1}{4}>0$$